# (object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) What does it mean?

Tags: c#, xna

It's an example from msdn.

```
public class Timer1
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed+=new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        // Set the Interval to 5 seconds.
        aTimer.Interval=5000;
        aTimer.Enabled=true;

        Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
        while(Console.Read()!='q');
    }

    // Specify what you want to happen when the Elapsed event is raised.
    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

My question is directed to this line:

```
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
```

What hides in 'source' and 'e' variables? I know, that they are function parameters, but what is send to them from event?

Comment: If I recall correctly, `source` should contain a reference to the Timer which dispatched the event, and `e` should contain information about what triggered the event, as described further in the documentation for the `ElapsedEventArgs` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source is the *source* of the event - in this case the timer; while e contains information relating to the event.  In this case ElapsedEventArgs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.elapsedeventargs_members(v=vs.80).aspx

Another example would be the keyDown event for a textbox in winforms - the e parameter gives you the KeyCode and lets you determine if the user was holidng Alt/Control, etc.

```
 txt_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
   ...
```

Answer (score 2):

well, the `source` should be whatever object invoked the event, which in this case seems to some `Timer`,

and `e` should contain more meta-information about the event.

For instance, if you have a `on-click` event the `...EventArgs` might tell you the coordinates where the click occurred.

If you're using Visual studio, you can type something like `e.` and then intellisence should tell you all that's in there.

Answer (score 1):

`source` is going to be the timer itself. `e` is going to tell you what time the event was triggered: [ElapsedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.elapsedeventargs.aspx).

Most of the time you're not going to concern yourself with either of those arguments. You just care about doing something when the timer is triggered so you can happily ignore the arguments passed to the method.